# Initialising a pandas dataframe with column names defined by a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to initilise a pandas dataframe with 1613 rows. I want to define the column names by the list 'indicns_list' (which has 471 elements). I tried this:

```
con_meds3 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(0,1613),columns=indicns_list)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1613, 471), indices imply (1613, 1)
```

help! :)

Comment: Can you reproduce this error with just `indicns_list = list("ABC")` and `con_meds3 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(0,1613),columns=indicns_list)`? If not, you have to provide code that allows SO users to reproduce the error message.

Comment: Just do `con_meds3 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,1613),columns=indicns_list)`.

Comment: I've just run several tests on this and cannot replicate. I presume there is an issue with the list.  If after inspection you determine the list of OK, please update the question so the issue is reproducible.

Comment: THANK YOU!
Yes I found that each element within the list was a list. This resulted in using the line indicns_list = indicn_counts.index.to_list()
like this.... 
['arthritis']
['hypertension']
['impotence']
['cold']
['constipation']
I used a hack to correct this list and the code above now works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their is issue in the `indicns_list` if below code does fine. try this

```
con_meds3 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(0,1613),columns=[i for i in range(1613)])
```

Comment: You are right - each element within the list was a list from using the line 
indicns_list = indicn_counts.index.to_list() 
So the list was like this.... ['arthritis'] ['hypertension'] ['impotence'] ['cold'] ['constipation'] I used a hack to correct this list and the code above now works :)